# Having trouble with os.startfile() on Mac and implementing a solution

Tags: python, macos, subprocess

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Text
import os, sys , subprocess


# holds the whole app structure
root = tk.Tk()
#shows app in interface
apps = []

if os.path.isfile('save.txt'):
    with open('save.txt','r') as f:
        tempApps = f.read()
        tempApps = tempApps.split(',')
        apps = [x for x in tempApps if x.strip()]
        print(tempApps)
# defining functions to add to the app interface

def addApp():
    for widget in frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select File",
                                          filetypes=(("apps","*.*"),("all files","*.*")))
    apps.append(filename)
    print(filename)
    for app in apps:
        label = tk.Label(frame, text=app,bg="gray")
        label.pack()

def runApps():
    for app in apps:
       os.startfile(app)





#creating our interface size and look
canvas = tk.Canvas(root,height = 700, width = 600, bg = "#263D42")
#showing the interface
canvas.pack()
#creating an inner white frame to hold the information
frame = tk.Frame(root,bg='white')
frame.place(relwidth=.8,relheight=.8,relx = 0.1,rely = 0.1)


#creating buttons for apps
openFile = tk.Button(root, text="Open File", padx=10,
                     pady=5,fg='black',bg='#263D42',command = addApp)

#shows app on the GUI interface
openFile.pack()
#creating buttons for apps
runApps = tk.Button(root, text="Run Apps", padx=10,
                    pady=5,fg='black',bg='#263D42',command= runApps)
#creating buttons for apps
runApps.pack()

for app in apps:
    label = tk.Label(frame, text=app)
    label.pack()


root.mainloop()

with open('save.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.append(apps + ',')
```

This app will be used to speed up the process in opening apps when first starting up your laptop in the morning, as of right now this application is only working on windows and I would like the Make it compatible on Mac OS as well. the problem is within the os.startfile() command, I would like to implement an if statement to read if it is a Mac or windows file and then take proper actions to open the applications/files given to the application.

Comment: Read about [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)

Comment: perfect solved it!

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

```
os.startfile(app)
```

by:

```
subprocess.call(["open", app])
```

to consider a specific app to use to open a file you can do this:

```
subprocess.call(f"open -a {application} {app}")
```

where `application` is the app that you want to open `app` by

Answer (score 0):

Try this kind of structure:

```
def runApps():
    for app in apps:
        subprocess.call(["open", app])
```